# process url's text using grep/sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have messing with grep (a bit newbie), but my grep skills aren't up to par.

So far I got

```
grep -Eo "//[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" file
```

Which isn't quite giving the output I'm after (then trim the output again), which is a bit ugly :( Is there a clean way to just grab the top level domain?

Input:

```
"asynch",websiteHost:"//cdn.www2.qqw-ab-mon.com",Myhost:"//
"asynch",websiteHost:"//cdn.www.qqw-cd-mon.com",Myhost:"//
"asynch",websiteHost:"//qqw-ef-mon.com",Myhost:"//
"asynch",websiteHost:"//cdn.ww.qqw-eh-mon.com",Myhost:"//
"asynch",websiteHost:"//cdn.qqw-ej-mon.com",Myhost:"//
```

Desired output:

```
qqw-ab-mon.com
qqw-cd-mon.com
qqw-ef-mon.com
qqw-eh-mon.com
qqw-ej-mon.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your all values will start from `qqw` then following may help you on same, in case they are not then please be more clear in your question with proper examples in it and will edit the code then.

```
awk 'match($0,/qqw.*com/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Would awk understand, awk 'match($0,/www(0-9).*com/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  (if www$num) existed?

Comment: @BridgetRoe, `www$num` is it a bash variable? kindly do let me know on same we could handle it but need more details on same.

Comment: Ah, found out awk 'match($0,/w.*.com/) should cover it